# how to wrap div elements boxes with responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to wrap div boxes into main div along with images with responsive.?
Am trying to achieve below layout.
[image: layout]

When i use `float:left` the boxes are aligned perfect where as without it if i use display inline block the boxes are not aligned as shown below.

[My jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkmail/c4cujv8s/)

[image: Boxes should be wrapped]

```css
.mywrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     min-width: 320px;
     max-width: 905px;
     background: yellow;
     
 }
 
.firstblock {
  margin-top: 60px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;     
     background: red;
     //background: #2b2b2b;
     padding:30px;
     width:auto;
  height:auto;
     
 }


 
.mainimage{
 width: 190px;
 height: 125px;
 margin-left:2%;
 float:left; 
 padding-right:30px;
}

.smallbox{
 float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right:10px;
    
}

.secondblock {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     height: 215px;
     background: aqua;
     padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mywrapper" id="myid">
    Hello
 <div class="firstblock">
 <div >
   <img class="mainimage" src="mainimg.JPG" border="0" />
  </div>
  <div>   
   <h2 class="title"><span>MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT</span></h2>  
   <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box1.JPG" alt="box1.JPG" border="0" /><span>box1</span><div>MY TEXT</div></div>
   <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box2.JPG" alt="box2.JPG" border="0" /><span>box2</span><div>MY TEXT MY TEXT</div></div>
   <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box3.JPG" alt="box3.JPG" border="0" /><span>box3</span><div>MY TEXT MY TEXT</div></div>
     
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="secondblock">
 secondblock
 </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little unsure as to exactly what you're trying to accomplish. You want the boxes to be displayed inline, but wrap around to the next line when there are more than can fit on one line?

Comment: @ObsidianAge updated my layout design that am trying to achieve for responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would like this

```css
.mywrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 905px;
  background: yellow;
}
.firstblock {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;     
  background: red;
  //background: #2b2b2b;
  padding:30px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
.left-div{
  float:left;
  width: 27%;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right:2%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.right-div{
  float:right;
  width:70%;
}
h2{
  margin-top:0;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
img{
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.pcspecimg {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 3%;
  width: 27%;
}
.small-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.smallbox {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  height: 110px;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  width: 32.3%;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.smallbox:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
.secondblock {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 215px;
  background: aqua;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mywrapper" id="myid">
    Hello
    <div class="firstblock">
    <div class="left-div">
      <img class="mainimage" src="mainimg.JPG" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-div">   
      <h2 class="title">
        <span>MY TEXT MY TEXT</span>
      </h2>  
      <div class="smallbox">
        <div class="small-wrap">
          <div class="pcspecimg">
            <img src="box1.JPG" alt="box1" border="0" />
          </div>
          <span>box1</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div>MY TEXT</div>
      </div>
     <div class="smallbox">
        <div class="small-wrap">
          <div class="pcspecimg">
            <img src="box1.JPG" alt="box1" border="0" />
          </div>
          <span>box1</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div>MY TEXT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox">
        <div class="small-wrap">
          <div class="pcspecimg">
            <img src="box1.JPG" alt="box1" border="0" />
          </div>
          <span>box1</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div>MY TEXT</div>
      </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondblock">
    secondblock
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mywrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     min-width: 320px;
     max-width: 905px;
     background: yellow;
     
 }
 
.firstblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 60px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;     
     background: red;
     //background: #2b2b2b;
     padding:30px;
     width:auto;
  height:auto;
     
 }


 
.mainimage{
 width: 190px;
 height: 125px;
 margin-left:2%;
 float:left; 
 padding-right:30px;
}

.smallbox{
 float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right:10px;
    
}

.secondblock {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     height: 215px;
     background: aqua;
     padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mywrapper" id="myid">
    Hello
  <div class="firstblock">
    <div>
        <img class="mainimage" src="mainimg.JPG" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div>   
      <h2 class="title"><span>MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT MY TEXT</span></h2>  
      <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box1.JPG" alt="box1.JPG" border="0" />                      <span>box1</span><div>MY TEXT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box2.JPG" alt="box2.JPG" border="0" />                      <span>box2</span><div>MY TEXT MY TEXT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="smallbox"><img class="pcspecimg" src="box3.JPG" alt="box3.JPG" border="0" />                       <span>box3</span><div>MY TEXT MY TEXT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="secondblock">
    secondblock
  </div> 
</div>
```

Is it you want?

Can You explain detail?

Comment: @krish Would you mind watching the full screen my code?

Comment: the layout breaks when it goes responsive(i.e. when i resizse window the boxes are coming out of the wrapper div element)